# How does web filtering software hook into outbound browser requests without browser configuration?

Tags: http, filter, proxy, filtering

I would like to duplicate the functionality of some web filtering software, however I don't want the user to have to configure their browser. [Some other products](http://www1.k9webprotection.com/) on the market do this without any apparent configuration in the browser settings.

The user would be installing this for themselves, so air-tight filter security is not a priority.  But ease of installation and the ability to apply to an arbitrary browser would be important.

Since the vision is standalone desktop software, inserting a filter on another upstream machine is not really an option.

Comment: Looking for windows equiv of: 
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp –dport 80 -j REDIRECT –to-port 8080

Answer (score 1):

You will need software that runs on a network node that all internet flows through, and it will have to intercept HTTP requests and redirect them accordingly.

Some routers have this sort of capability, it can also be accomplished with linux routers using iptables and a squid proxy.

Comment: Perhaps a valid answer considering that the LOCAL node is itself a "network node that all internet flows through".  Now.... how to intercept the HTTP requests and redirect them?

Answer (score 0):

Install your program as a proxy for all HTTP traffic.

Comment: on Chrome (as example), that wouldn't work by default... still need to turn some knobs.

Comment: I think that is the question.  How do you install your program as a proxy for all HTTP traffic?

Comment: That is the question.  Not having to configure the browser is a goal.

Answer (score 0):

[Windows Filtering Platform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366510%28VS.85%29.aspx)

> [Windows Filtering Platform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366510%28VS.85%29.aspx) (WFP) is a set of API and system services that provide a platform for creating network filtering applications. The WFP API allows developers to write code that interacts with the packet processing that takes place at several layers in the networking stack of the operating system. Network data can be filtered and also modified before it reaches its destination.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366510%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Only available on Windows Vista and newer.